# What is the difference between JSSE and JCE?

Tags: java, cryptography

What is the difference between JSSE and JCE. Both these deal with encryption in a broad case. My question might have been not clear. As JCE provides encryption which we can use to encrypt the data then why we need to use JSSE for secure sockets which also provides encryption?

Comment: You can just read what they are... JSSE adds for SSL and TSL capabilities, while JCE provides generic encryption capabilities.

Comment: This question is too broad; at least describe what you don't understand about the differences after reading the description of the two technologies.

Comment: Both these deal with encryption in a broad case. My question might have been not clear. As JCE provides encryption which we can use to encrypt the data then why we need to use JSSE for secure sockets which also provides encryption.

Answer (score 6):

Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) provides cryptographic, key and hash algorithms for the Application Server. JCE provides a framework and implementations for encryption, key generation, key agreement, and Message Authentication Code algorithms. Support for encryption includes symmetric, asymmetric, block and stream ciphers.

Whereas JSSE provides the transport security for the Application Server. JSSE provides the application programming interface (API) framework and the implementation of the APIs for Secure Sockets Layer and Transport Layer Security protocols, including functionality for data encryption, message integrity, and authentication.

Answer (score 5):

JCE or rather the JCA provides an *architecture* for offering so called *cryptographic primitives*. Cryptographic primitives are specific forms of cryptographic constructions. For instance, it provides primitives such as 3DES in CBC mode and AES in GCM mode (among others) for `Cipher`, which provides an abstraction of a cryptographic cipher. Others are SHA-1 and SHA-256 as cryptographic hashes, represented by the `MessageDigest` class.

JSSE however provides an architecture for a specific set of *protocols* called SSL and TLS. These protocols *may be* build upon the cryptographic primitives provided by the JCE. JSSE offers abstractions such as certificate verification and validation that different JSSE providers may use to implement TLS with X.509 authentication - the most common method of authentication for TLS. TLS is a set of complex protocols and ciphersuites which require implementation.

The fact that a *cryptographic provider* for JCE/JCA - such as the default ones provided by the standard JDK offered by Oracle - provides certain primitives doesn't mean that they are automatically integrated into a JSSE provider; just like having a sack of tasty nuts won't make them automatically appear on your apple pie. They need to be programmed into the JSSE provider to make them work within a TLS connection.

TLS uses a lot of cryptography, and you can be pretty sure that the crypto providers are kept up-to-date to allow JSSE to implement the latest / most common / required TLS protocol versions. Possibly to a fault, as functionality that isn't directly related to TLS and (and possibly CMS) may be missing from the standard API.